# QR decomposition using Householder reflections: how to calculate Q?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, linear-transformations

In a recent assignment, I was asked to develop a program that could solve some specific problem **using QR decomposition to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors**. That assignment also specified that we should use Householder reflections to find the QR decomposition of a matrix. 
To find the Householder transformations of a matrix, one can do it in two ways:

1. Given a vector $\vec v$, we can define the transformation matrix $H_v$ as $$H_v = I_n - 2*(\vec v\ \vec v^\intercal)/(\vec v\cdot \vec v)$$
   where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$. Then the transformation is applied by simply multiplying $H_v$ by the desired matrix.
2. To avoid doing some $\mathit O(n^2)$ calculations, it is suggested that we apply the following formula to apply the Householder transformation on a vector $\vec x$:$$H_v\vec x = \vec x  - {\vec v \cdot \vec x \over \vec v \cdot \vec v}\vec v$$ that way it is possible to obtain the transformed vector doing only dot products and scalar multiplications. One can apply this transformation to every column in a matrix in order to obtain the resulting transformation.

For the QR decomposition you can, for an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ do the following transformations: in the ith iteration, you set $\vec v_i = \vec a_i + sign(a_{ii})* \Vert \vec a_i \Vert   \vec e_i $ (where is $\vec a_i$ is the ith column of the matrix, $sign$ is the signal of a number and $\vec e_i$ is the ith canonical vector) and apply a Householder transformation (using method two listed above) to the matrix. After $n-1$ iterations you should reach an upper triangular matrix, that will be matrix $R$.
Now, matrix $Q$ is defined as the product of all Householder transformations you used to find $R$ ($Q = H_{v_1} H_{v_2} ... H_{v_{n-2}} H_{v_{n-1}}$).

In the context of the problem, I need to do multiple decompositions to find a matrix eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Assuming the eigenvalues are $\vert \lambda_1 \vert \gt \vert \lambda_2 \vert \gt ... \gt \vert \lambda_{n-1} \vert \gt \vert \lambda_n \vert$ you may approximate them using the following method:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Iteration} & \text{1# step} & \text{2# step}\\
\hline
1 & A_1 = Q_1R_1 & A_2 = R_1Q_1 \\
2 & A_2 = Q_2R_2 & A_3 = R_2Q_2  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
k-1 & A_{k-1} = Q_{k-1}R_{k-1} & A_k = R_{k-1}Q_{k-1}
\end{array}$$
$A_k$ will converge to an upper triangular matrix where the diagonal elements are the original matrix eigenvalues. Now, to find the eigenvectors you should multiply all the matrices $Q_i$ (assuming the original matrix was symmetric) which will give a new matrix $V$ ($V = Q_1 Q_2 \ ... Q_{k-1} Q_k$) where each column represents the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue of the same column (in the matrix $A_k$).

**What I don't know is, what is the point to use the second method to find $R$ if you need all the transformations matrices to find $Q$? Won't you need to calculate them all? Also, to find $V$ you need to have all matrices $Q$ explicitly calculated, don't you?**

Also, I have asked my professor and he wasn't sure about what I should do, but he gave the suggestion to calculate the first transformation matrix and use the following $v$s I found to multiply $H_{v_1}$ in the same way I did with $R$. Although, it didn't work correctly for me. I was hoping someone to know a better method to find $Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve a system $Ax = b$ with the QR-decomposition of $A=QR$ we ususally do this in two steps. First compute

$$y = Q^t b \qquad \text{ then } \qquad y = R^{-1}b$$

Since $y^t = b^t Q$ you have to compute multiple products of the form $w^t H_v$ which can be done exactly the same way as you already described. This way you can **avoid computing $Q$ alltogether**, and this is also the way it is sometimes done in numerical applications. (see e.g. [Numerical Recipes, chapter 2.10](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/))

Comment: hmm, I think that makes sense in the context of solving a linear system, but is it applicable in a numerical method to find the eigenvalues(I may not have made clear I was using QR for this application) of the matrix ?(decomposing $A_1$ then making $A_2 = R Q$ and repeating this process until $A_n$ is close enough to an upper triangular matrix) If so, how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method of computing eigenvalues, but it also involves a multiplication with $Q$ which can be decomposed in multiple multiplications of Householder matrices. So in this case you do not actually need $Q$ explicitly either.

Comment: Okay, so I don't need to multiply all the Householder matrices to find $Q$, but still, I have to calculate the matrix? Also, I'm still not sure of how I should apply that on the problem. How I'm supposed to find $A_2 = RQ$ if I only have $R$ and multiple matrices of $Q$ which I shouldn't multiply?

Comment: You know that $Q = H_{v_1}H_{v_2}$ so you can just iterate $y_1 = R H_{v_1}$ and $y_k = y_{k-1} H_{v_k}$ to get $y_n = RQ$. And in each of those iterations you compute the product using the method you described.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I think I just needed to think broader than before, I was focusing on finding Q while I should focus on how I was going to use it in my calculations. Thanks!